# How to define a TikZ coordinate at the point of intersection of two paths without drawing the paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to define, inside a TikZ picture, a coordinate as the intersection of two lines, or more generally of two paths, without drawing the lines (paths)?

For instance, consider the following LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p) at (.5,0);
\fill (p) circle (1pt);
\node [anchor=north] at (p) {P};

\draw (-1,0) -- ++(60:3);
\draw (1,0) -- ++(120:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following drawing.

[image: Intersecting lines]

I'd like to define a coordinate at the point of intersection of the two line segments for later use, for instance for drawing the line that coincides with the point P as well as with the point of intersection of the two line segments, but without drawing the segments.

How can this be done?

---

**An attempt at a solution**

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p) at (.5,0);
\fill (p) circle (1pt);
\node [anchor=north] at (p) {P};

\path [name path=left] (-1,0) -- ++(60:3);
\path [name path=right] (1,0) -- ++(120:3);

\coordinate[name intersections={of=left and right}] (q) at (intersection-1);

\draw (p) -- (q);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this yielded the following error in Overleaf (using the 2022 LuaLatex engine):

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 ...{of=left and right}] (q) at (intersection-1)
                                                  ;
```

Comment: By using `path` instead of `draw`?

Comment: The options of the `coordinate` will be executed later than when `intersection-1` will be tried to be accessed. You will need `\path[name intersection=…] coordinate (q) at (intersection-1);`. Or you use the [`by` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#tikz/intersection/by) and then you don't even need a path: `\tikzset{name intersection={of=left and right, by=q}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (p) at (.5,0);
        \fill (p) circle (1pt);
        \node [anchor=north] at (p) {P};
        
        \path[name path=line 1] (-1,0) -- ++(60:3);
        \path[name path=line 2] (1,0) -- ++(120:3);
        \path [name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2,by=K}];
        \draw (K) -- (p);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below, the same drawing with `path` on the left, and with `draw` on the right:

[image: intersetion without drawing lines]

Comment: See also `pgfinterruptboundingbox` (pages 1079-1989).